# MYSQL - Return the data in integer format with max function

Tags: mysql

I have a column with 20 digit numbers. When I use the following query, it is not returning the data as expected

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `card` (
  `id`        bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `value`    varchar(30) DEFAULT NULL,
)
```

Data:

```
ID       value
1         98765123450987654321
2         NULL
3         98765123450987654323
4         98765123450987654324
```

Queries used:

```
select max(value) + 1 from table;
SELECT CAST(value AS UNSIGNED) + 1 from table;
select CAST(max(value) AS UNSIGNED) + 1 from table;
```

Error Message:

```
BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range in '(cast(max(`table`.`table`.`value`) as unsigned) + 1)'
```

Without the cast it is returning 9.8765123e+19

Expected Result Example:

```
98765123450987654321
```

Comment: please show your table structure (output of `show create table yourtablename`)

Comment: @Barmar the supposed duplicate question is nothing of the kind; unsigned bigints only support 19 digits.  voting to reopen

Comment: @ysth I updated the description with the table structure and sample data

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: version is 8.0.23

Comment: cast to a decimal type:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bf00f50a0808bc1965f87c72112dad6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsigned bigints are restricted to 2**64, enough for a few but not all 20 digit numbers.  You can cast to a decimal type though:

```
select max(cast(value as decimal(30,0))) + 1 from card
```

though even decimal types will support at most 65 digits.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1bf00f50a0808bc1965f87c72112dad6)